# Left align one element and center another element in div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get one element to be aligned to the left, and another to be aligned to the center within a div.

However, this aligns both elements to the center. How do I align the Facebook icon to the left, while centering the `p` element?

```css
.panel-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-footer .fa-facebook {
  text-align: left;
}

.panel-footer p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/facebook" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <p>This website is made by ME!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @nedrathefr are you wanting the text in the p centered for the whole width of the page or centered within the p (minus the amount it has moved left because of the icon)?

Comment: @cale_b - care to say **why** you recommend against `position: absolute`?

Comment: @cale_b I'd hazard a guess that `absolute` is actually the only way to go here (just guessing, but think about the layout the OP is trying to achieve). I think it's unlikely that the desired layout would be satisfied by centering the text within it's `p` element rather than within `.panel-footer`. I've been doing this for a while too and know that it takes a long time to learn exactly when to `position` and when not to `position`. Don't try and label it as bad because it's often misused. It doesn't create more challenges than it solves, when it's used correctly, as is done in my answer below.

Comment: @Adam - totally agree.  I guess to my way of thinking, if OP has any control at all over the markup, I'd recommend modifying the markup to create the left, right, and center "containers" that are desired, and then the problem is trivial to solve with flexbox or inline-block.  If I've mislabeled absolute as bad, I apologize - I _did_ revise my comments a few minutes ago to temper that sentiment, so let me know if you still think it reads that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolute position the facebook icon. Make sure you leave enough padding to the left of the `p` element to account for it (so that the `p` text doesn't overlap it). Make the padding is equal on both sides to make sure you `p` text doesn't overlap and it's still perfectly horizontally centered inside `.panel-footer`

```css
.panel-footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-footer .fa-facebook {
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   /* vertically center the icon */
   top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.panel-footer p {
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 0 20px; /* leave space for the icon adjust this value depending on how big your icon is */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="panel-footer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/facebook" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <p>This website is made by ME!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

I would use flexbox for this:

```css
.panel-footer {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  align-items:center; /* vertical align */
}

.panel-footer p {
  flex-grow:1;       /* take up rest of line */
  text-align:center; /* centre text in p */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/facebook" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook">left</a>
  <p>This website is made by ME!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tricky here, the `p` text isn't technically centered horizontally because it's pushed from the left by the size of the icon. Is that what the OP wants? It's not clear to me.

Comment: depends if OP wants it truly centred within the whole line or within it's own element - I took the guess of within it's own element.  I will ask the question and update my answer based on the reply

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this page, it looks like the way to go now is to use flexbox.

Basically

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Center</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;"></div> <!-- placeholder; important to give it some width-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.align-center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/facebook" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook float-right">Link text</a>
    <p class="align-center">This website is made by ME!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: _"How do I align the Facebook icon **to the left**"_

Comment: just switch `float: right` to left. Also as an option you can make special class just for center alignment like `class="align-center"` and then `.align-center { text-align: center; }` add this class to your fb icon. It's enough.